# Morphisms of the varieties and coordinate rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm thinking something very wrong but I can't find what the flaw in my thinking is.  Well, here goes.

First, if a contravariant functor $\mathsf{F}: \mathscr{C}\to \mathscr{D}$ is a category equivalence, then it sends epimorphisms (or monomorphisms) to monomorphisms (or epimorphisms), right? Moreover, given a field $k$ algebraically closed, the functor that sends a variety $V$ to its coordinate ring $k[V]$ is a category equivalence.

Well, consider $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ and the inclusion map $(\mathbb{A}^n - V(f)) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n$.  Well, the map in the coordinates rings is the localization map $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]_f$, which is clearly not surjective.  What have I done so wrong here?

Comment: One issue: epimorphisms are not necessarily surjections on the underlying sets. A map out of $S^{-1}A$ is totally determined by what it does to the elements $a/1$.

Comment: but aren't they surjections in small categories?

Comment: oh. hmm. I guess not.  So are epimorphisms are exactly the surjections only in the category $\mathsf{SET}$?

Comment: "only" is a very strong statement. epimorphisms are surjections on the underlying sets in $A$-mod, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Epimorphism need not be surjective on underlying sets in concrete categories. In other words, there is a forgetful functor from $k$-algebras to sets, and this functor does not preserve epimorphisms. (Exercise: it *does* preserve monomorphisms.) Essentially every localization is an epimorphism in $k$-algebras, but not a surjection.

See also a sequence of blog posts I wrote starting [here](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/) that thoroughly discusses these and related issues.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post, was a nice read